# Creating a directory for a class in school on Github

Tags: git, github

I want to make a directory in one repository with all of the projects for each of my classes on GitHub but I can't for the life of my figure it out.

I want to do this for job interviews and future employers to show off my coding abilities.

I want a master directory called classes

Within it I want CS1, CS2, CS3.. etc

Within CS1, I want all of the projects in different folders with the code and Xcode projects for them as well as the .h and .cpp files..

I am on a mac and have tried command line, the desktop application, and adding them via the site but have no luck

Comment: There's no way you can add an empty directory with Git - it tracks files, not folders. Maybe try adding a small `.gitignore` file inside each to at least give them contents?

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to create a folder called classes in Finder. Then within that folder initialise a git repository using the command, `git init`. Then add the folders you want for your different class projects. You will then need to go to GitHub.com and create a repo. You will then receive instructions to link your local repo with the GitHub repo. Once this is done use the command `git add .` to add all your files and folders to a commit. Then to initialise the commit use the command `git commit -m "enter your commit message here"`. Then push your code to the GitHub repo using `git push`